# apply css to a list of classes in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have a list of images, with the same class name in my dom as follows:

```
<a href="#"><img class="vote" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_XeuZ1yDnv4Q/TSUkAT6T1dI/AAAAAAAADR8/nPHP4JvVxy8/s1600/vote.jpg"></a>

<a href="#"><img class="vote" src="http://bgathinktank.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/vote-button.jpg"></a>
```

now say given a list of widths in a js array

```
width = [100, 200]
```

i want the first image to have a width of 100 and second one a width of 200.

How can that be done using jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$('.vote')` finds all elements with class '.vote'.
2. [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) iterates through all images. The callback can receive two parameters: the current index and the current DOM element. We don't need the latter as `this` is also the current DOMelement in the callback.
3. [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) sets the width of each element in the matched set, here the current image `$(this)`

Here's the code:

```
var width = [100, 200];
var $imgs = $('.vote');

$imgs.each(function(idx) {
    $(this).width(width[idx]);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Ayshw/)**

Answer (score 1):

`$('.vote').each(function(index){$(this).width(width[index])});`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img.vote').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('width', width[i]);
});
```